# Solution to trigonometric derivative

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

## Version 2

For

\begin{align}
&x(t)\text{:=}\cos (t)+\cos (2 t)+1&\\
&y(t)\text{:=}\sin (t)+\sin (2 t)&\\
\end{align}

how would I go about proving that the solutions to

\begin{align}
t\in\mathbb{R}:\frac{2 \left(x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2\right)^{3/2}}{\left| x'(t) y''(t)-x''(t) y'(t)\right| }=\sqrt{x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2}
\end{align}

are

\begin{align}
t=2\pi n-\cos^{-1}(-5/4),n\in\mathbb{Z}\\
t=2\pi n+\cos^{-1}(-5/4),n\in\mathbb{Z}\\
t=\dfrac{2}{3}(3\pi n-\pi),n\in\mathbb{Z}\\
t=\dfrac{2}{3}(3\pi n+\pi),n\in\mathbb{Z}\\
\end{align}

as given by Wolfram|Alpha?

---

## Version 1

For

\begin{align}
&x(t)\text{:=}\cos (t)+\cos (2 t)+1&\\
&y(t)\text{:=}\sin (t)+\sin (2 t)&\\
&a(t)\text{:=}\sqrt{x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2}&\\
&b(t)\text{:=}\sqrt{x(t)^2+y(t)^2}&\\
\end{align}

how would I prove that the real roots of
$a(t)=\dfrac{2}{b(t)}$ are at $\pm\dfrac{2 \pi }{3}\pm2 \pi\  n,\  n\in \mathbb{Z}\ ?$

## Update

Sorry for the lack of clarity. I am including a plot to help clarify what I mean:

[image]

As Git Gud pointed out in the comments, I think I am really after $$t\in\mathbb{R}:a(t)=\dfrac{2}{b(t)}$$

## Update 2

I apologise to Galc127 who gave an excellent answer in spite of my mistake. $b$ should actually be

\begin{align}
b(t)\text{:=}\frac{\left| x'(t) y''(t)-x''(t) y'(t)\right| }{\left(x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2\right)^{3/2}}
\end{align}

This results in the plot given, and fits the solutions given - have been talking cross purposes as a result & am very grateful to Galc127 and others I have caused confusion to! Again, I apologise - feel free to downvote as seen fit!

NB Plot for original question:

[image]

So to clarify, question *should* have been what are solutions to

\begin{align}
t\in\mathbb{R}:\frac{2 \left(x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2\right)^{3/2}}{\left| x'(t) y''(t)-x''(t) y'(t)\right| }=\sqrt{x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2}
\end{align}

Comment: I get that $a(t)=\sqrt{5+4\cos t}$, which doesn't have any real roots.

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but I think the term 'root' is with respect to functions or polynomials, not equations. You're asking to find the roots of an equation which leaves me guessing what is it exactly that you want.

Comment: @GitGud _Mathematica_ gives me the above solution, but I was after the steps (or hints on how to get there) - a plot clearly shows the periodic "roots" (or whatever the correct expression is)

Comment: @martin I still don't know what you want. Do you want $\{t\in \mathbb R\colon a(t)=0\}$ or $\left\{t\in \mathbb R\colon a(t)=\dfrac 2{b(t)}\right\}$?

Comment: If $a(t) b(t) =2\;$ then for obviously bounded $b(t)\;$ there can be no zeros of $a(t)$.

Comment: @GitGud The latter is what I am after

Comment: @martin, the numerator is probably $|x'(t)y''(t)-y'(t)x''(t)|$ and not as written.

Comment: @Galc127 It would be when $2$ is divided by it

Comment: @martin, look on the numerator as it written - $|x'(t)y''(t)-y''(t)x'(t)|$ which is clearly $0$.

Comment: @Galc127 Sorry - I'm having one of those days!

Comment: @Galc127 OK - I think that's staightened out now

Comment: @martin, my post is edited and there are solutions to both versions.

Comment: @Galc127 Thank you so much for your patience! I have updated the question to match the format of your answer.

Comment: Happy to help and upvote for editing the question to match both versions.

Comment: @Galc127 Thanks once again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Version I:**

By simplifying:
$$x(t)=\cos(t)+\cos(2t)+1=\cos(t)+2\cos^2(t)-1+1=2\cos^2(t)+\cos(t) \\ x(t)=\cos(t)[2\cos(t)+1] \\ y(t):=\sin(t)+\sin(2t)=\sin(t)+2\sin(t)\cos(t) \\ y(t)=\sin(t)[2\cos(t)+1]$$
Therefore $x(t)=\cot(t)\cdot{y(t)}$.

Also:
$$x'(t)=-\sin(t)-2\sin(2t)=-y(t) \\ y'(t)=\cos(t)+2\cos(2t)$$

Now we can write: $$b(t)=\sqrt{x(t)^2+y(t)^2}=\sqrt{\cot^2(t)\cdot{y(t)^2}+y(t)^2}=\left|\frac{y(t)}{\sin(t)}\right|$$

If so, then $b(t)=\left|2\cos(t)+1\right|$.

Now, $$a(t)=\sqrt{x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2}=\sqrt{\left[-\left(\sin(t)+2\sin(2t)\right)\right]^2+\left[\cos(t)+2\cos(2t)\right]^2}$$
Simplifying:$$a(t)=\sqrt{\sin^2(t)+4\sin(t)\sin(2t)+4\sin^2(2t)+\cos^2(t)+4\cos(t)\cos(2t)+4\cos^2(2t)}$$
Using the identities $\displaystyle \sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$ and $\displaystyle \sin(x)\sin(y)+\cos(x)\cos(y)=\cos(x-y)$ we get $$a(t)=\sqrt{5+4\cos(t)}$$
Eventually, our equation becomes $$a(t)=\frac{2}{b(t)} \Rightarrow \sqrt{5+4\cos(t)}=\frac{2}{\left|2\cos(t)+1\right|}$$
Now, $5+4\cos(t)=2\left[2\cos(t)+1\right]+3$. Define $2\cos(t)+1=x$ we get the equation $$\sqrt{2x+3}=\frac{2}{|x|} \rightarrow |x|\sqrt{2x+3}=2 $$

This leads to a cubic equation which has one real root ($x \approx 0.91082$) and from here you can find the values of t.

---

**Version II**

$$x'(t)=-(\sin(t)+2\sin(2t)) \rightarrow x''(t)=-(\cos(t)+4\cos(2t)) \\ y'(t)=\cos(t)+2\cos(2t) \rightarrow y''(t)=-(\sin(t)+4\sin(2t))$$

Now we can find an expression for $b(t)$: $$\displaystyle b(t)=\frac{\left|x'(t)y''(t)-y'(t)x''(t)\right|}{\left(x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2\right)^{3/2}}\\ \small b(t)=\frac{\left|(\sin(t)+2\sin(2t))(\sin(t)+4\sin(2t))+(\cos(t)+2\cos(2t))(\cos(t)+4\cos(2t))\right|}{a(t)^3}$$

The equation is $a(t)=\frac{2}{b(t)}$, hence $$a(t)=\frac{2a(t)^3}{\left|(\sin(t)+2\sin(2t))(\sin(t)+4\sin(2t))+(\cos(t)+2\cos(2t))(\cos(t)+4\cos(2t))\right|}$$

We should simplify the denominator, so $$\displaystyle \small\left|(\sin(t)+2\sin(2t))(\sin(t)+4\sin(2t))+(\cos(t)+2\cos(2t))(\cos(t)+4\cos(2t))\right|= \\ =\displaystyle \small \left|\sin^2(t)+6\sin(t)\sin(2t)+\sin^2(2t)+\cos^2(2t)+6\cos(t)\cos(2t)+\cos^2(2t)\right|$$

Using the identities $\displaystyle \small \sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$ and $\displaystyle \small \sin(x)\sin(y)+\cos(x)\cos(y)=\cos(x-y)$ we get that $$\displaystyle b(t)=\frac{2a(t)^3}{\left|9+6\cos(t)\right|}$$

Our equation becomes $\displaystyle a(t)=\frac{2a(t)^3}{\left|9+6\cos(t)\right|}$.

It is clear that $a(t) \ne 0$, hence $\displaystyle \left|9+6\cos(t)\right|=2a(t)^2$.

From version I we know that $a(t)=\sqrt{5+4\cos(t)} \rightarrow a(t)^2=5+4\cos(t)$, thus $$\left|9+6\cos(t)\right|=2(5+4\cos(t))=10+8\cos(t)$$

There are two options to check in order to find the solutions.

Comment: thank you for your answer - I will go through it now!

Comment: @martin, I made some edits.

Comment: And by the way the solutions are $\pm{1.615}+2\pi k \ \mathrm{for\,} k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Hmm, that is strange. WolframAlpha gives

\begin{align}
t=2\pi n-\cos^{-1}(-5/4),n\in\mathbb{Z}\\
t=2\pi n+\cos^{-1}(-5/4),n\in\mathbb{Z}\\
t=\dfrac{2}{3}(3\pi n-\pi),n\in\mathbb{Z}\\
t=\dfrac{2}{3}(3\pi n+\pi),n\in\mathbb{Z}\\
\end{align}

Comment: @martin, You might want to check W|A solutions in the final equation.

Comment: yes will do. But it looks fairly clear on the plot ...

Comment: What are the functions you have plotted? Plot $\sqrt{5+4\cos(t)}$ and $\displaystyle \frac{2}{\left|2\cos(t)+1\right|}$. What do you get?

Comment: I am so sorry! I wrote the question incorrectly (see update 2). I will accept your answer in spite of my mistake - no wonder there has been some confusion! Thank you so much for your help though.